# ActiveRecord order by columns from multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Lets say I have a User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
  ...
end
```

and both `Post` and `Comment` have a `created_at` column.

How can I order Users based on the latest `created_at` column of both `posts` and `comments` combined using ActiveRecord?

I know I can use the Ruby's `sort` method but that is too slow.

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej Combined as in treating created_at from both posts and comments as if it's from the same table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use PostgreSQL:

```
# Users with most recently created posts/comments go first
User.left_outer_joins(:posts, :comments)
    .group('users.id')
    .order('GREATEST(MAX(posts.created_at), MAX(comments.created_at)) DESC')

# .. and go last
User.left_outer_joins(:posts, :comments)
    .group('users.id')
    .order('GREATEST(MAX(posts.created_at), MAX(comments.created_at)) ASC')
```

For MySQL the code seems to be the same.